# null-coalescing operator in the getter

Tags: c#

in c# is there a difference between the following

```
//syntax 1
    private ICommand newWindowCommand;
    public ICommand NewWindowCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return newWindowCommand = newWindowCommand ?? new MVVM.RelayCommand(...);
        }
    }

    //syntax 2
    private ICommand newWindowCommand;
    public ICommand NewWindowCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return  newWindowCommand ?? new MVVM.RelayCommand(...);
        }
    }

    //syntax 3 the usual way 


    private ICommand newWindowCommand;
    public ICommand NewWindowCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (newWindowCommand==null)
            {
                newWindowCommand = new MVVM.RelayCommand(...);
            }
            return newWindowCommand;
        }
     }
```

in case 2 does it set newWindowCommand to the value that has been returned or do i have to assign it as in case 1?

Comment: What happened when you debugged and checked?

Comment: I would always prefer syntax 3 because it is clear what happens! As soon as you, the author of the code, have to think about what happens with one of the alternate solutions, you can be sure that any maintainer of your code will also have to think twice. Sacrificing intuitive code just to save four lines is really BAD!

Comment: @gehho That's true up to a point. That point being that one must learn the syntax of case 1 (and the preferable syntax of Joe's answer). Having learnt it, it becomes just as readable as case 3 *and* takes up less space. So I'd prefer that syntax over case 3 any day.

Comment: @DavidArno I do not agree. You could also argue that you should learn how to write a complete application on one line, or how to use `goto`-statements properly (exaggerated a litte, I admit). Sure, it is all possible, but it is not intuitive. And even if you and I understand syntax 1, a new developer in the company will probably not understand it, but he will certainly understand syntax 3.

Comment: @gehho Any new developer has a duty to learn such syntax. The more they are exposed to good use of such features, the quicker they will learn. I would expect the same for linq query syntax, lamdas etc. Restricting oneself to only basic language features through fear of having to then teach the "good bits" to others is ridiculous IMO.

Comment: @DavidArno I see your point, but I simply do not consider this a "good bit" or a "good use of such features". And I am not talking about the `??` operator in general (I also use it for simple checks), but about the combination with an assignment which has to be put in parentheses. You can see in the comments to joe's answer that it causes confusion. Anyway, I think we simply have different preferences and will not agree. You will use it, I will not. That's okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case 2 `newWindowCommand` is not assigned.
Case 3 is the same as case 1, but the long way.

Use this: (appears a lot in my code)

```
get {
    return newWindowCommand ?? (newWindowCommand = new MVVM.RelayCommand(...));
}
```

This will first check if `newWindowCommand` is assigned. If not, it will then create a new instance, assign it and return it.

It's different from case 1 (brackets), because the `??` operator has [higher precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6a71f45d.aspx) than `=`.
Therefore the `(` and `)` ensures that `=` is first executed, then `??`.

Comment: you might wanna explain why you'd prefer this to case 1

Comment: i would like to know that too, is there a difference?

Comment: @user1492051 Your case 1 will always assign the member variable even if it isn't null, as it assigns to itself. In this example, the check is done before an attempted assignment. The brackets are required to resolve the assignment into a `string`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth are you sure that the JIT is unable to see that the value doesn't change and therefore that it's a no-op that can be disregarded?

Comment: @RuneFS No idea, it might do. I tend towards code whose behaviour I can read.

Comment: Though I generally agree but if you do not know what the optimizer will do with the code how do you expect that your interpretation of the code is any more correct than the next? It's highly likely it will be optimized a way and using assignments as expressions in C# is generally discourage (to the extend that someof them are either a compiler warning or even an error) so in this case there's also the consideration of "least surprise". I don't favour one or the other. For the reason you state and for "least surprise" one's guaranteed not to assign and the other is closer to C# in general

Answer (score 2):

Case 2 will not set `newWindowCommand` and so `new MVVM.RelayCommand(...);` will be invoked every time.

Answer (score 2):

Your case 2 and 3 are functionally the same but the IL is different and depending on the optimizations they might therefor have different charateristics with regards to e.g. thread safety. That's not something I'd suggest choosing on unless it's an identified problem for this piece of code.

whether or  do

```
get {
    return newWindowCommand ?? (newWindowCommand = new MVVM.RelayCommand(...));
}
```

or

```
get {
    return newWindowCommand = newWindowCommand ?? new MVVM.RelayCommand(...);
}
```

would probably end up with the same optimized code since potentially extra the assignment in the latter is redundant.

There's another option to all of these using `Lazy<T>`

```
  Lazy<IComand> newWindowCommand = new Lazy<ICommand>(()=> new MVVM.RelayCommand(...));
  get {
    return newWindowCommand.Value;
  }
```

You can further customize the initialization e.g. with regards to thread safety. If there's no thread safety concerns I'd suggest to go with the one you believe is more readable and expresses the intent the purest. If you have thread safety concerns then I'd suggest to go with `Lazy<T>` regardless of which you think is more readable. Thread safety is difficult to get right so I'd always use BCL implementation if available

Answer (score 1):

Sure, in case syntax 2 the `newWindowCommand` will remain unitialized (null)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you set the newWindowCommand field elsewhere in code, it will always be null in case 1 and 2.

Another thing with this kind of lazy initialization. If multiple thread access your command property at the same time new RelayCommand can be initialized several times. You need to synchronize the code:

```
get
{
    lock(syncobject)
    {
        return newWindowCommand ?? (newWindowCommand = MVVM.RelayCommand(...));
    }
}
```

The ICommand method will probably never be used in other situations than through binding. The binding mechanism will retrieve the command just once, therefore you probably wont need to store the command reference in your viewmodel.

```
public ICommand NewWindowCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MVVM.RelayCommand(...);
    }
}
```